# Apply multiple analyzers in hibernate search?

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

**Can we use multiple analyzers on a field to search a text using hibernate search??**

For example : 
Initially I want to use Japanese Analyzer if nothing is found then N-Gram Analyzer will be picked automatically for searching.

Is there any support like above in hibernate search?? And if not then how can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you tell us things that you have already tried.. what was the output and what was expected..

Comment: I'm implementing this functionality by creating new annotation as I didn't find this support in hibernate search. I don't think such support is implemented in hibernate search. Well, there must be a reason for it and I want to know this.

Answer (score 1):

A single field in Lucene should be processed by a single Analyzer, and this should be consistent across the index or it becomes hard to define queries: defining a correct query generally needs to know which analyzer is being used by a specific field.

If you need properties to be analyzed in multiple different ways, to correct approach is to use the `@Fields` (plural form) annotation to map a property to multiple index fields.